# jQuery and JavaScript scrolling and Responsive site all jacked up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a portfolio site using Scrollit.js, http://bytemuse.com/scrollIt.js/, jquery-1.10.2.min.js, and a Responsive Grid System http://www.responsivegridsystem.com. I guess this is a bit out of my league, because it's all jacked up. Here is what's happening:

[image]

^That blue shouldn't be there, but isn't a problem in a smaller window.

[image: Not really a big problem]

^Not really a big problem

[image]

^Here's where it gets jacked up. The background should be white, and the blue should not be peeking through on the top and bottom. This is a problem in a smaller window as well.

[image]

^... Just, ugh. Very frustrating.

I've been tampering with my code for hours and I have no idea what to do next. If anyone could make a suggestion I would really appreciate it! Here's a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/p28w9/ I think the problem will be found somewhere in this CSS snippet, but I can't really put into words why, and I can't be sure if I'm right. That's why I need some help. >.<

```
/*  SECTIONS  */
section {
    padding-top: 60px;
    height: 838px;
    width: 100%;
}

#work {
    margin-top: 200px;
    padding: 50px;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
    padding-top: 260px;
    height: 320px;
    background-color: #1ab7ea;
    color: #fff;
}

/*.section {
    clear: both;
    padding: 0px;
    padding: 20px;
}*/

section .content {
    margin: 160px auto;
    max-width: 640px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem i can pinpoint straight away is the height that you are setting for your sections.
I would recommend you to use **at least** 1200px height and leave the padding-top the same to all your sections.

```
section {
padding-top: 80px;
height: 1200px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Also on your section nth-child you shouldn't be setting extra height or padding as this is messing up your Scrollit. Css below would work fine for you.

```
section:nth-child(odd) {
background-color: #1ab7ea;
color: #fff;
}
```

Another thing i want to mention is that on higher that 1200px resolution (on the Y Axis) will result on having a part of the next page, at the bottom of the previous page. So before starting your portfolio you should ask yourself what's the max resolution you would like your website to work good with.

Hope this will help you,

Regards,

Thanos

Comment: you could also use `height:100%;` and fill all the screen in all resolutions